# display images from json object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i'm trying to output a series of images in html from an external json file. Unfortunately i cannot change the way the json is formatted and i can't seem to find the right way to access the image urls to use them as src attribute.
this is the code i came up with

```
$.getJSON( "json/data.json", function( data ) {

var mhtml = '';
$.each(data["item"].images, function(key, val){

for (var i=0; i< data["item"].images.length; i++) {
var img = data["item"]images[i];
}

var alt = data["item"].name;
    mhtml += '<li><div class=""><img src="'+val.img+'" /></div>';
    mhtml += '<h1 class="title">'+alt+'</h1>';
    mhtml += '</li>';
});
var $ul = $('<ul>').append($(mhtml));.
$('#mydiv').append($ul);

});
```

it successfully counts the images and outputs elements but i can't access the url parameters.
this is how the json file is formatted

```
{
"item": {
    "name": "blue dress",
    "details": "graphic print, Logo.",
    "composition": "Composition: 94% Cotton, 6% Elastam.",
    "modelDetails": [
        "Modeal wearing a size M",
        "Measures: 86 - 60 - 90",
        "Height: 178cm"
    ],
    "images": [
        "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_001.jpg",
        "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_002.jpg",
        "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_003.jpg",
        "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_004.jpg"
    ]
}
}
```

thanks everyone for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues.

1. looping over the images twice - $.each is a loop
2. getting the alt each time.
3. val.img does not exist

Here is a working version - do make sure it is run after mydiv exists

```js
data = {
    "item": {
        "name": "blue dress",
            "details": "graphic print, Logo.",
            "composition": "Composition: 94% Cotton, 6% Elastam.",
            "modelDetails": [
            "Modeal wearing a size M",
            "Measures: 86 - 60 - 90",
            "Height: 178cm"],
            "images": [
            "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_001.jpg",
            "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_002.jpg",
            "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_003.jpg",
            "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_004.jpg"]
    }
}

var alt = data["item"].name,mhtml="";
$.each(data["item"].images, function (i, img) {
    mhtml += '<li><div class=""><img src="' + img + '" /></div>';
    mhtml += '<h1 class="title">' + alt + '</h1>';
    mhtml += '</li>';
});
var $ul = $('<ul>').append($(mhtml));
$('#mydiv').append($ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can help you

```
var data = {
"item": {
    "name": "blue dress",
    "details": "graphic print, Logo.",
    "composition": "Composition: 94% Cotton, 6% Elastam.",
    "modelDetails": [
        "Modeal wearing a size M",
        "Measures: 86 - 60 - 90",
        "Height: 178cm"
    ],
    "images": [
        "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_001.jpg",
        "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_002.jpg",
        "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_003.jpg",
        "http://cdn.myoutfits.biz/41/xxxxxxx_004.jpg"
    ]
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log(data.item.images);
  var alt = data.item.name;
  var mhtml="";

    $.each(data.item.images,function(k,v){
      mhtml += '<li><div class=""><img src="'+data.item.images[k]+'" /></div>';
    mhtml += '<h1 class="title">'+alt+'</h1>';
    mhtml += '</li>';
    })

    alert(mhtml)


 console.log(mhtml)
$('#mydiv').append(mhtml);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kz2WI6FEk0atgoUFJ0Jf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you do a **foreach** and a **for** ... i don't understand why you do the internal cicle (the for).

If you change

```
mhtml += '<li><div class=""><img src="'+val.img+'" /></div>';
```

into

```
mhtml += '<li><div class=""><img src="'+val+'" /></div>';
```

you can see some image